# Reentrant lock condition

Tags: java, multithreading, locks

I wanted to create class Suspender that allows to pause and resume threads anytime you want, but unfortunately nothing happened after calling `condition.signalAll()`. Can someone tell me, what is the reason?

```
public class Task extends Thread{

    private Suspender suspender;

    public boolean paused = false;

    public Task(Suspender suspender){
        this.suspender = suspender;
    }

    public void resumeThread(){
        suspender.resume(this);
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Pausing");
        paused = true;
        suspender.pause(this);
        System.out.println("Resumed");
    }
}

public class Suspender{

    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    public void pause(Task current) {
        try{
            lock.lock();
            while(current.paused){
                condition.await();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void resume(Task current) {
        try{
            lock.lock();
            current.paused = false;
            condition.signalAll();
        }finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

}

public class Start{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Suspender suspender = new Suspender();

        Task t1 = new Task(suspender), t2 = new Task(suspender);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        t1.resume();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        t2.resumeThread();

        t2.join();
    }

}
```

Comment: "*I wanted to create class Suspender that allows to pause and resume threads anytime you want*" -- you can want that all you like, but you're not going to get it without cooperation from the underlying scheduler.  You cannot implement it on top of your threads.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Are you talking about ScheduledExecutorService? Started learning lock just a moment ago.

Comment: No, @Razor, I am talking about the thread scheduler of your threading implementation.  For Java implementations that use native threads (i.e. most of them), that's part of the operating system.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Okay, Is there any other way to pause and resume threads using locks?

Comment: I should clarify, @Razor: threads can make *themselves* suspend execution by awaiting a condition variable, as your code demonstrates, or they will be blocked if they try to acquire an exclusive lock that is held by a different thread, among many other possibilities.  But none of these is a general and arbitrary "any time you want".

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oh, okay. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you intentionally invoking the deprecated `Thread.resume()` method on `t1`, or did you mean `t1.resumeThread()`, instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your main thread calls `t1.resume()`, but your `Task` class declares `public void resume(Task current)`. Those are two *different* methods. Java allows different methods to have the same name if they have different argument lists. When your main thread calls `t1.resume()` it is calling a [deprecated method of the `Thread` class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#resume()), which will have no effect because the thread never was suspended.*

---

* Note: [suspended](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend()) is not the same thing as awaiting a condition.